# Complete numbers on Clock

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, lateral-thinking, number-sequence, formation-of-numbers

I have a different kind of clock at my home. Image of Clock:

[image]

5 o'clock on this clock means 1 o'clock actually. Display of data in table:

[image]

Can you complete all the numbers on this clock by finding type of clock?

**HINT 1:**

> As everyone going in wrong direction so its a hint to point you to right direction or to result:)    [image]

**HINT 2:**  One more example data to reduce possibilities..

> [image]

**HINT 3:**

> It works around display of numbers...

Comment: hmm... hands of the clock are so weird.

Comment: hey, i notice something different on hint 1, is it an infinite symbol (on bottom side)?

Comment: @athin, its not infinite symbol, think another way:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, i think i got it now.

> The numbers are based on their 7-segment displays
>      [image]
>  Where a number's value is equal to the sum of all lit-up segments
>
>  For example, with 1:
>  [image]
>  So [1] = 2 + 3 = 5.
>
>  We can see that it applies to every other revealed number too:
>  [2] = 1 + 2 + 7 + 5 + 4 = 19.
>  [7] = 1 + 2 + 3 = 6.
>
>  For numbers with more than one digit, do this for both digits and sum their totals.
>  [11] = [1] + [1] = 5 + 5 = 10
>  [12] = [1] + [2] = 5 + 19 = 24

Doing this for all numbers, we get

> [image]

Comment: You definitely got it...!

Comment: I can't believe i didnt notice that [11] = [1]+[1] and [12] = [1]+[2] from the table! Had to wait for that last hint before things finally connect :P

Answer (score 2):

> [image]

I assumed 19[2] + 5[1] = 24[12]

so concluded 24[12] - 10[11] = 14[10]

24[12]/4 = 6[3] -- 1/4th of 24

24[12]/2 = 12[6] -- half of 24

24[12]/4*3 = 18[9] -- 3/4th of 24

19[2] + 6[3] = 25[4]

18[9] + 14[10] = 32[8]

32[8] - 12[6] = 20[7]

25[8] - 12[6] = 13[5]

**Reasons for different calculations:**

Value for 3, 6, 9 based on 24 by dividing the clock in 4 quarters

> [image]

The 3 points of black triangle are points that have total values.

The 3 points of blue triangle add value of next point to it to get the total of nearest black point value clock wise and anti-clockwise.

Comment: I am new here :) please tell me the reason while downvoting

Comment: Can you explain the thoughts behind your answer? Why is it that you use division for [3], [6], [9], [12], but then switched to additions and subtractions? Why is [2]+[3] = [4] but then [9]+[10]=[8]? and [8]-[6]=[7]? For me it looks like you're just randomly mashing the numbers you have together to fill all the slots with no rhyme or reason

Comment: I'll try to explain @VotBear

Comment: @Mehravish Temkar, Thanks for trying but sorry to say you are not on right track, what i can say is you don,t need to assume numbers or finding any relationships between both clocks like this.

Comment: I see that in your clock, [12], [4] and [8] are the sums of the two numbers after/before them. But i can't figure out how you can get to this conclusion based on the initial question...

Answer (score 1):

My answer is:

> [image]

Reasoning:

> It seems the difference between each subsequent hour is 14, but since hour 11 on your clock has a lower value than earlier hours, I figured that there might be a [modulo operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) being applied. The modulo divisor needed to produce 10 by the hour 11 and also had to be greater than 24 which is the value of hour 12. The lowest possible one that worked was 27. So the formula for your clock, given hour *n* on a normal clock, is $(14*(n - 1) + 5)\ \%\ 27$. That said, since there are other modulo divisor's that work the correct answer is probably something more clever than this.

Comment: Thanks for trying but not correct sorry, doesn't require tough maths

Answer (score 1):

[image: This is the solution i think]

I think the odd numbers have a sequence counter clockwise, and the even numbers have the same sequence counter clockwise, which is the number minus five, unless it's gonna be a negative number. also, 24+5, 10+19, 29+0, 15+14, 4+25, and 20+9 is every time 29 as illustrated in the next image.

[image: it all adds up!]

Because the numbers add up to 29, which is 24+5, this is indicating a hint that you have to add 5 to the odd AND even numbers on the clock every time.

Comment: nice try:) but not the answer i am looking for, sorry